# Cannot access my Web App with iphone

Tags: amazon-web-services

As the title implies, I can't seem to access my web app ([r24-staging.resourcefull.cc](https://r24-staging.resourcefull.cc)) using any iphone device with any browser on iphone. But I can access it in any browser on Linux/Windows.

The Web App is hosted in AWS with EC2 and ELB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem there's a problem using http2 for some reason, and from what I've read it's probably because of invalid headers.

```
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: r24-staging.resourcefull.cc
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c]
* HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* Closing connection 0
```

You can test this by [disabling http2 on your AWS load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#load-balancer-attributes).  If that fixes the problem then you need to find out where the invalid headers are coming from and fix that before you can turn http2 back on.

I was able to confirm this theory by disabling http2 in my request:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: r24-staging.resourcefull.cc
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

Comment: omg thanks. However, I have no idea where this header is coming from. Is this on application level?

Comment: From what I’ve read in other posts it might be a confing issue.  Unfortunately I’ve never used AWS so I can’t offer any insight, and this is the wrong forum for it.  Maybe try server fault.

Comment: This made the difference for me. On Safari the website was only loading like 50% of the time, same results for `curl`. It worked fine in Chrome, 100% of the time. Removing HTTP/2 from the load balancer fixed it. Thanks!